# How to interleave Kernel/Vertex METAL Shaders

Tags: metal, metalkit

I'm coming across deploying a Metal render loop as a chain of multiple 
KCS (kernel/compute) shaders and VFS (vertex/fragment) shaders:

```
texture -> [KCS -> VFS -> KCS -> VFS] --\
                                         --->[KCS -> KCS] --> presentable
texture -> [KCS -> VFS -> KCS -> VFS] --/
```

The output of one shader is the input to the next.  The two sets of 4 alternating shaders are combined near the end, as shown.

If I'm thinking this through rightly, I'll need up to 10 disparate pipeline descriptors in order to make this happen, along with a lot of calls to completion handlers in which the next shader will be dispatched.

*I also haven't indicated it, but the last call to presentable will also feed subregion of its output fed into a separate MTKView (via a vertex/fragment shader).*

**Any hints would be appreciated.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need different descriptors if they would have different values. That is, if any of the KCS steps you show use the same compute shader function, then they typically can share a descriptor. (There are other properties of `MTLComputePipelineDescriptor`, but they're less commonly used.)

For the VFS steps, the descriptor is more complex and so they'd have to be equal across all properties to be shared.

Of course, you should be creating your pipeline state objects once in the lifetime of your app, if you can. Avoid creating them for every render loop.

You definitely **don't** want to use completion handlers to dispatch the next step. That will stall the pipeline horribly (make the CPU and GPU wait for each other, repeatedly). Just encode the steps in order into a command buffer. Any given draw or dispatch won't proceed until any previous draw/dispatch that might write to its inputs has completed.

Comment: A prompt response, yet again, Ken!  Simplifying this a bit, I'd have a set of VFS MTLRenderPipelineDescriptors and a set of KCS MTLRenderPipelineDescriptors and one MTLCommandBuffer?  I'd end up creating encoders on the fly in the command buffer, and they'll be executed in order -- even if they're interleaved KCS/VFS? Also, can I have those pipeline descriptors shared (and used) across multiple MTKViews?

Comment: Well, you'd have a set of `MTLRenderPipelineState` and `MTLComputePipelneState` objects. You'd create the descriptors at the time of creating those state objects, but you wouldn't need to keep them. (Also note: you can configure a descriptor, create a state object from it, reconfigure that same descriptor, create a different state object from it, etc. So, you wouldn't necessarily need a descriptor per state object.) You'd need one command buffer per iteration of the render loop, encode to it, commit it, and drop references to it.

Comment: Yes, the encoded commands will execute in order. The GPU may actually parallelize commands which don't depend on each other's results, but the effect is as if they executed in order. And, yes, you can share state objects across render targets, etc. Basically, there's never a need to create redundant state objects (i.e. from equivalent descriptors). The state object just reflects the values in the descriptor at the time it was created, with certain precomputation done during that creation.

Comment: One question I do have... let's say I have a Compute Encoder (kernel shader) and I'm expecting an output buffer/texture from it after doing a "dispatchThreadGroups".  I can't see a way around issuing an "commit" to the command buffer and then adding a completion handler (or just "waitUntilCompleted") before scheduling the next batch of work, using the texture output as an input to the next (say) vertex shader.  Or am I overthinking things -- you seem to indicate that the encoder is smart enough to "pause" the vertex shader work with the outBuffer ref being an inBuffer ref to the vertex shader.

Comment: The commands you encode to a command buffer using various encoders are semantically executed sequentially. That's how you should think of them happening. It's possible that the GPU can parallelize them, but only if it maintains the outcome that would have resulted from executing them serially.

Comment: Thinking of it as "pausing" the draw operation is a bit strange. Remember, it's a render command **encoder**. A call to a "draw" method is just encoding a draw command to the buffer. It doesn't directly start a draw operation. Eventually, you commit the command buffer with a whole bunch of commands encoded to it. Those commands are then performed in sequence. So, it's just a natural consequence of the command buffer that the draw doesn't begin until the compute shader has completed.